# Deploying a Qt program with a logo to load

Tags: c++, qt, pdf, qt5

I have developed a program for a customer which includes a functionality to save and print PDF files. In this PDF file there should be a company logo attached.

I am using the `QPrinter` function to both create and print the PDF file. To add the logo I use the function `drawPixmap`. The logo itself is a JPG file. Originally I just added the file to my program folder and used `QDir::currentPath() + "/" + "logoName.jpg"`. It worked flawlessly on my computer but at the customer it can not load the file using the `load()` function from QPixmap:

```
QPixmap companyLogo; 
companyLogo.load(QStringPathToFile);
```

I have verified that the string is correct using `entryInfoList()` and compared it to the path I send to QPixmap.

I learned about resource files in Qt and how you could add a resource, like an image, to the binary. Again, it works flawlessly on my PC but at the customers PC it fails to load. I have verified the behavior on a secondary PC here in the company.

```
companyLogo.load( ":/logo/CompanyLogo.jpg" )
```

It seems like a such simple thing to do. But I am always hit a wall with this logo. Do anyone have any information how I can get this logo/image to load properly when deploying my Qt program to another PC?

Comment: when you use ressource files the logo is compiled into the binary so the customer can't change it unless he compiles the program himself. Using a path should be the way to go. Are you using relative paths? The working directory may be different when you start the program on your machine. I'd suggest a [QFileDialog](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html) and the absolute path from it to the `load()` function. That should work IMHO

Comment: Hello Bowdzone. First of all thanks for the formatting. Did'nt work out very well for me but now I can see how you did it when I press 'edit' :)
You bring up a valid point but I have seen problems with Qt when changing between system languages. E.g I use English so my default director is C:/Program Files (x86)/MyProgram. At my colleague it is C:/Programmer (x86)/MyProgram. When the program I compiled calls QDir::currentPath() on his PC then it returns the English path and not the Danish. Using resource files removes this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to deploy jpeg plugin from /plugins/imageformats/qjpeg.dll

Have a look [here](https://wiki.qt.io/Deploy_an_Application_on_Windows) about how to deploy on windows

Comment: Hello Jeka. 
Thanks a lot. That did it. 
I must have missed this page when I a few months ago read about Qt deployment on Windows because I have never seen this page before.